# How to implement a function that will return when an intense string is passed in, and false otherwise?

Tags: javascript, string, function, for-loop, if-statement

Strings are intense if they end in three or more more ! marks. However, having ! marks anywhere but the end makes for a non-intense string.

The issue I'm having is when there is an ! in the middle of a string. The result should be false but it's still resulting as true.

My code:

```
function intenseString (str) {
  if (str.slice(-3) !== "!!!") {
    return false;
    } 
  else if(str.slice(str.indexOf("!"))){
    return false;
    }
  else if(str.slice(-3) === "!!!"){
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code, with some formatting tweaks for readability:

```
function intenseString(str) {
  if (str.slice(-3) !== '!!!') {
    return false;
  }

  if (str.slice(str.indexOf('!'))) {
    return false;
  }

  if (str.slice(-3) === '!!!') {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Can you give some example inputs that return `true`? I don't think this will ever return `true` because the second `if` statement says "return false if there are any `!`'s in the string, which is implied by passing the first `if`.

I believe you meant to add `+ 1`: `if (str.slice(str.indexOf('!') + 1)) return false` which says "return false if there are any `!`'s that are not the last character in the string", which still won't work: The first `if` statement will return false if the string doesn't end with `!!!` meaning that the smallest string that would get to the second `if` statement is `!!!` and there will always be characters after the first `!`.

Another potential attempt would be to only check the string before the last three characters `if (str.slice(0, -3).slice(str.indexOf('!') + 1)) return false`, which almost works except for strings containing more than 4 `!` at the very end... (such as `!!!!!`).

I don't see a simple way (without regex to check that the remaining characters are only `!`) to make the second `if` statement work without looping over the string.

*Note that your final `if` is unnecessary. Your first two are checking for failure and if they pass through them, it must be an intenseString. Also the string must end in `!!!` if it got past the first `if`.*

---

Here's a potential solution which goes through every character in the string, except for the last 4, and returns `false` if there is ever an `!` followed by something that is not an `!`.

```
function intenseString(str) {
   if (!str.endsWith('!!!')) {
       return false;
   }

   for (let i = 0; i < str.length - 4; i++) {
       if (str.charAt(i) === '!' && str.charAt(i + 1) !== ('!')) {
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of slicing the string:

```js
const strings = ['abc!!!', 'abc!!de', 'abc!']

const intenseString = (str, chars) => str.indexOf(chars) >= 0

console.log(strings.map(x => intenseString(x, '!!!')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these ways:

```
function intenseString(str) { return str.slice(-3) === '!!!'; }

function intenseString(str) { return str.endsWith('!!!'); }

function intenseString(str) { return /!{3}$/.test(str); }
```